# After one minute we have to high output for two or three seconds. How can we design a circuit using 555 timer IC without using a microcontroller?

Tags: rf, power-electronics

After one minute we have to high output for two or three seconds. How can we design a circuit using a 555 timer IC without using a microcontroller?

We need to reduce the cost using alternate method instead of a microcontroller.

Comment: You just program it into the microcontroller. If the microcontroller is doing nothing else, even a for loop delay would work. If it is doing something else, then timer interrupts. It's almost the simplest program you could write that actually does something.

Comment: *We need to reduce the cost* The 555 needs resistors and a capacitor. There are microcontrollers that only cost a few cents (when bought in large numbers) and such a solution is cheaper than any 555 based circuit.

Comment: The 556 is a dual version of the 555, just in case.

Comment: On 'microcontrollers are cheap', see my comments below on how that ignores engineering costs and actual final costs.

Comment: Cheap depends on your expectations for design cost and production cost and volume. WIthout specs. No answer is valid. There are big tradeoffs

Answer (score 1):

You can use two 555 monostable multivibrators with the 1 minute one triggering the second. You'll also need something like an RC or a reset chip to generate the power-on trigger for the first one, assuming that's what you want.

But a microcontroller quite likely will be cheaper to build. It will certainly be simpler and more accurate.

Comment: But actually demand of our client is to complete a task on the low cost, we need to use 555 timer or other alternative method instead microcontroller.

Comment: @SalmanRaheem So use a cheap microcontroller instead of just assuming a cheap 555 timer AND some cheap resistors AND some cheap capacitors together cost less than one cheap microcontroller. There are microcontrollers that cost pennies.

Comment: please Recommend what are my options for cheap microcontrollers

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here. You know they exist now. Go find them. You're the one getting paid for it, not me.

Comment: @DKNguyen, unfortunately, the 'microcontrollers are pennies' is purely an electronics view of it and a naive one. A hobbyist in a shed having fun flicking through a parts catalogue and comparing part prices can do that. It's not an engineering solution and professional electronics engineering is all about the engineering. Whatever the application, in a professional engineering environment the software must be developed, documented, tested and released. At, let's say £60..100/hr total cost (not just salary) of an engineer, depending where/who for, you've got min. 1 person/week or £2k4..4k...

Comment: ...for this tiny project in total, more for bigger designs. That week also has board test procedures work, which was low for std parts but now needs a spec'. Then prodn programming cost, obsolesence (nil for 555+discretes, high risk for MCU) etc. Now spread those costs over the total cost, see how much the 'pennies' part cost has leapt up. And try that in volume commercial, aerospace, military, automotive,  medical etc. Costs are paramount, not technical solutions. Quality engineering is good cost control over all aspects of product/design life cycle, it's not just churning out circuits...

Comment: ... I'll cheerfully use an MCU - once I've established all the real costs, for the client (company) I have and their market, standards, life cycle requirements and reliability figures. These answers must consider they situation an OP is in, or be broad and explain the variations they'll be faced with. Designing the circuit is the relatively easy part of meeting the design requirements - that's just electronics.

Comment: @TonyM OP's original question was worded such that he wanted to replace 555 timers with a microcontroller while at the same time also saying they were too expensive.

Comment: I do see your point @DKNguyen and I'd first read OP original question before commenting. But my comments were replies to yours about MCU cost of use. As an aside, the 'just use an MCU' thing comes up often on this site, though nowhere near as bad as it used to be, and it practically always ignores the cost of implementation. I've most often found it a hard/impossible point to get across on this site and the total opposite in the real pro world - you're regarded as a simpleton there if you haven't got it running in your veins. I've seen that over decades in many companies. Business comes first.